# ReactJs overlay Font awesone Icons

Tags: reactjs, icons, font-awesome

I want to ask how we can stack Font Awesome icons in ReactJS.

In HTML we use the following code:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

And in ReactJS we use:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFlag} />
```

How to stack a circle on user so that it looks as if Flag icon is in circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can do something like that and play with `positioning` and `flex`:

```
.the-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.the-wrapper .icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

</style>

<span class="fa-stack fa-2x the-wrapper">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} />
  <div class="icon">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFlag} />
  </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "layering" with the provided CSS to do the same:

```
<span className="fa-layers fa-fw fa-2x">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} />
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFlag} inverse transform="shrink-5" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions didn't work well for me. Here's what I did:

```
<div>
    <span className="fa-stack">
        <FontAwesomeIcon className="fa-stack-2x" icon={['fas', 'fa-circle']} />
        <FontAwesomeIcon
            className="fa-stack-1x"
            icon={['fas', 'fa-flag']}
            transform="shrink-3"
        />
    </span>
</div>
```